# Solidity: logical AND outputs parser error

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm totally new to solidity and programming in general but I stumbled on an issue in my code when trying to use the "and" operator with my if statement:

```
        if (multiBlockRandomGen(5715713, 10) >= 512) && (y > 1) {
            /*rest of the code*/;
        }
```

it outputs an "ParserError: Expected primary expression" error on the first "&" character.
I've looked everywhere and I'm not sure what the problem is.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Syntax error logical and operator is outside of if statement. After fixed syntax error you code would be:

```
    if (multiBlockRandomGen(5715713, 10) >= 512 && y > 1) {
        /*rest of the code*/;
    }
```

Let me know any issues your facing

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the syntax was like that